# Excel VBA comparing a date to a time and copying another cell into a column

Tags: excel, vba, loops, date

I have two variables in my excel worksheet which are a date(cell A1)and a time(cell B1)when I fill these in it’s results in a value(cell C1) trough allot of formula’s. now what I want to do with VBA is that it automatically puts in all the dates and times from 1 year and copies the data from cell C1 and puts its into a column ranging from 1 to 8761 so 1 data point for every hour in one year. I’m totally inexperienced with VBA so it’s probably not even that hard but I just don’t know how to do it.

I’ve tried allot but I’m not experienced enough to fix it

Comment: you're more likely to get a response if you add an example/code

Comment: I’ve tried allot .... show something!

Answer (score 1):

You can put the starting date into the first cell, say A1, then set A2 = ***a1 + 1/24*** and copy it down as far as you need it.

In VBA, this could be

```
Range("A1") = the starting date, say "1-1-2022'
for i = 1 to 8760
Range("A1").offset(i,0) = starting date + i/24
next i
```